# UITableView cell not diplaying images horizontally

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to have only one uitableview cell which can display horizontally as many images as it receives from server. But the problem is currently I receive say 15 images from the server and the cell only displays first 6 images and does not display rest 9 images. However, I can see the horizontal scroller scrolling till the end as i have made the contentsize according to size of 15 images. Following is the code (for testing purpose I am retrieving image from resource folder instead of getting from server ).

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

    CGFloat imageXCordinate = 0.0;
    int i =0;
    for(i=0; i < 15; i++)
    {
            NSString *filePathForIconPhotoImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon_photo" ofType:@"png"];
            UIImage *iconPhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathForIconPhotoImage];

            UIImageView *vwIcon=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageXCordinate,2,iconPhoto.size.width,iconPhoto.size.height) ] ;
            vwIcon.image =iconPhoto;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:vwIcon];
           [vwIcon release];
            [iconPhoto release];

            imageXCordinate = imageXCordinate + basePhoto.size.width;

    }

        [tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((basePhoto.size.width * i, tableView.frame.size.height)];
  }
```

NOTE:
1. I know I can use a UIScrollView instead but still want to use UITableView for some specific reasons. 
2. I have created a UITableView programmatically and placed it in the [self.view addSuvView:myTableView].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why exactly do you need a table view? if you want to scroll horizontally within a cell, you can add a UIScrollView to a cell. If you want to scroll horizontally within the whole area you display your images in, UIScrollView is your perfect solution. There are numerous tutorials available fur subview tiling that allow you to create reusable views (similar to dequeueing cells) if you have a large number of images to display

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you could point to me to a tutorial about reusing scrollView to load and display images on scrolling  that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have an apple developer account you can watch the wwdc 2010 session videos (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). The session you want is named "Designing Apps with Scroll Views". wwdc 2011 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) had a follow-up session "Advanced ScrollView Techniques"

Answer (score 1):

following link will definitely   help you

[how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)